# adding products in itunes connect

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

I developed an app with in app purchase enabled and succeeded in doing it. I could test my app in the sandbox environment, and the in app purchase getting done as desired. I added the products manually by visit itunes connect website earlier. Though I am happy for the whole process, I struck with a new idea what if there are 100's of products? Should I add all the hundred products manually?

Is there any way to directly add all my products from my server to the itunes, taken care that all the information of the products (identifier, price ,category, etc) are provided in the server along with the products?

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted. The question isn't written very well, but the point is well taken; I'm somewhat interested myself as to what people will recommend.

Comment: tnx steve. i am too surprised by the down vote....

Comment: Have you heard about any updates on this matter?

Comment: @JulianOsorio Recently one of my friend was saying he has done this using application loader.In application loader there is a column "Create new package" -new from file -upload a file.  file should contain your products info with tab seperated.I think you can try if it works and mean while i would capture more details this time when i again meet him and update you.

Comment: @Dinakar Thanks. I am checking it right now and it seems there is a change with it. I will update any break trough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way that I am aware of to batch upload in-app purchase data.  The web site not only requires you to add product IDs, price, etc, but also upload a photo so that it can be reviewed by Apple.  It is, for now, a manual process.